# Redis Network Load

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, predis

Currently my application is using redis for cache, queue and session. For queue and session i don't encounter any issue but on cache, it seems it is using more network load than memcached. It is exactly the same codebase, the difference is only on the cache driver(redis/memcached).

Just for comparison, during site peak hours, memcached only used 250 Mbit/s, while on redis the network load can go up to more than 1 Gbit/s. So it becomes an issue when we use redis behind a load balancer device, as it's reached the maximum throughput for that load balancer and also the redis server network card(currently only use 1 gigabit network card)

Just additional information, my application is using php laravel framework, while client library for redis is using predis.

I am just curious why redis could use more then 4 times network load than memcached. I am looking for some way for redis compression so it would not send too much data across the load balancer and redis server.

Please kindly advise if you've encountered this issue before